# Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args - trying to run ionic project on ios device

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, build, device

I am trying to get an earlier commit of my ionic project working. I download it, install any required packages (`ionic-native`) that aren't installed that should be, I can build it fine with `ionic package build ios` - it's just getting it to upload to device. Here is the error output that it spits out at the very end right before it would load onto the device:

```
...

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-bnwtqimovpcmyxaamvattontsmzm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myApp normal arm64
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/eamonwhite/Downloads/ionicmane-82759f57fa193e7843d98642ee1dcf795d58659b/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,myApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,myApp,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,myApp.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/eamonwhite/Downloads/ionicmane-82759f57fa193e7843d98642ee1dcf795d58659b/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/eamonwhite/Downloads/ionicmane-82759f57fa193e7843d98642ee1dcf795d58659b/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run ios --device (exit code 1).
```

I have done all the code signing stuff in xcode that needs to be done, and repaired any warnings - so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

**UPDATE**

I have `<engine name="ios" spec="~4.4.0" />` in `config.xml` and I have - `"cordova-ios": "~4.4.0"` in `package.json`. Before trying this I updated `cordova-ios` to 4.5.1 and tried it with no luck. Then I downgraded back to 4.4.0 (as suggested) by running `npm uninstall cordova-ios && npm install cordova-ios@~4.4.0` - it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Recent error with new version of Cordova iOS engine.

Change the following in your config.xml

```
<engine
 name="ios"
 spec="~4.4.0"/>
```

**Note** : **^** replaced by **~** for version 4.4.0

Now you will be able to run your ionic project onto your Device without any Errors.

Comment: do u mean config.xml? and i don't have an` <engine>` tag...should i just add it?

Comment: also i got past this error...but it is hanging on the splash screen...could this be a reason that is happening still?

Comment: Yeah its Config.xml (edited the answer). It is required to add <engine> in config.xml to make cordova to understand for what you are going to build for. May be your splashscreen error can also be resolved after the changes that aligns with the answer given above. Just try and let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: in trying some things before ur response...i have it so that when i do `ionic cordova platform add ios` it adds the `engine` line with `^4.5.1` now...(i updated it at somepoint and now it is defaulting to that version)...do i just still change the `^` to a `~` to make it work still?

Comment: i just tried that and im still getting the same error

Comment: Version 4.5.1 is the Major bump which also caused us the ERROR. Just go with version 4.4.0. use the ~ for applying latest Patch.

Comment: is there a way to make 4.4.0 the default again? or can i just use the number in there and it will be fine?

Comment: and by 'use the ~ for applying latest patch` you mean just change it in the config.xml?

Comment: im going to update my question with what i did...it still is giving me the error

Comment: one thing i just noticed is `ionic package build ios` works while `ionic cordova build ios` throws the error.

Comment: this is also a commit that i took from git to work on because i mucked up the latest version of what im doing...i did `npm install` and had to fix a few other errors...but i eventually got it building...it just hits this error...is there anything i could be forgetting with getting the project ready to build/deploy...i opened xcode and did the code signing as well as doing the "suggested updates".

Comment: I busted through some dependency errors and that change helped me get it back to the point where it is hanging on the splashscreen...any ideas why that is happening? i have another question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632515/ionic-app-hangs-on-splash-screen