# Ionic - app hangs on splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, deployment, splash-screen

My ionic app is hanging on the splash screen - it was working fine and then I added some code, and went to test, and it's getting stuck.

It gets to this point:

```
------ Debug phase ------
Starting debug of 2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356 (N51AP, iPhone 5s (GSM), iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'Eamon White’s iPhone' connected through USB...
[  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[ 90%] Mounting developer disk image
[ 95%] Developer disk image already mounted
[100%] Connecting to remote debug server
-------------------------
(lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/2F06F4BB-A7E5-4B97-87EC-A01CBEE5661A/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356'
Executing commands in '/tmp/2F06F4BB-A7E5-4B97-87EC-A01CBEE5661A/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356'.
(lldb)     platform select remote-ios --sysroot '/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols'
  Platform: remote-ios
 Connected: no
  SDK Path: "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols"
(lldb)     target create "/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device/myApp.app"
Current executable set to '/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device/myApp.app' (arm64).
(lldb)     script fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EBCC0EF-FDB9-4DE7-A961-D91B6139AEA0/myApp.app"
(lldb)     script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:50188"
(lldb)     target modules search-paths add /usr "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols/usr" /System "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols/System" "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EBCC0EF-FDB9-4DE7-A961-D91B6139AEA0" "/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device" "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EBCC0EF-FDB9-4DE7-A961-D91B6139AEA0" "/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device" /Developer "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols/Developer"
(lldb)     command script import "/tmp/2F06F4BB-A7E5-4B97-87EC-A01CBEE5661A/fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.py"
(lldb)     command script add -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.connect_command connect
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.run_command run
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.autoexit_command autoexit
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.safequit_command safequit
(lldb)     connect
(lldb)     run
success
(lldb)     safequit
Process 7681 detached
```

The `deviceready` message never comes.

One thing I did that is kind of relevant is, when I was building or something ionic asked me to upgrade `ios-deploy` from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2. I think this started happening after I did that. I try to revert back to 1.9.1 but it won't let me:

```
ld: framework not found MobileDevice
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Release/ios-deploy normal x86_64
(1 failure)
npm ERR! Darwin 17.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.3/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy@1.9.1"
npm ERR! node v7.7.3
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.9.1 preinstall: `./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 65
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.9.1 preinstall script './src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ios-deploy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ios-deploy
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ios-deploy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/eamonwhite/Downloads/ionicmane-master/npm-debug.log
```

That might not be the problem. I could really use some help I'm close to a deadline.

**UPDATE**

When I try to run in `xcode` the same thing happens, but `xcode` gives these errors:

```
2017-10-10 15:49:17.417901-0400 myApp[8476:3520766] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-10-10 15:49:38.433127-0400 myApp[8476:3520766] Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.
```

**UPDATE**

I figured out what was causing this - it's `livereload` - if I run it without that its fine...but I kind of need it to work to develop.

Comment: What do you mean by get stuck ? Are you getting a blank screen after the splash or are you getting a infinite loading splash screen.? 

Any Screenshots possible ?

Comment: thanks, infinite loading splash screen - its just my splash screen and the loading wheel in the middle stays circling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't have my `wifi` enabled on my phone so it couldn't connect to `ionic`.

Comment: Here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697733/livereload-causes-app-to-stall-on-splash-screen-continuous-loading-wheel-ion

Comment: This was the case for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience we have the same issue `deviceready` is never shown in our console log, the most possible case would be inconsistency of the Cordova Plugin one thing that you could do is to reinstall the plugins and try to delete your platform folder and make a clean build with `npm cache clean` .

**Update:**

Based on your update , how are you running your ios app ?

Are you running your app using the `-l -c` commands like below:

`ionic run ios -l -c`

if that is the case you may be noticed that this command changes a line in the `config.xml` file:

// from
`<content src="index.html"/>`

// to
 `<content src="localhost//192.1.168.0:8000" original-src="index.html"/>`

So Changing it back to `<content src="index.html"/>` might fixes the issue.

**Solution 2:**

You probably need to whitelist the localhost in the following way:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100/*"/>
```

Comment: thanks i think ive tried this ill try it again..."reinstalling means" deleting node_modules folder, reinstalling, and then `platform rm/add` and then `npm cache clean` and then `ionic build` - also, if I am still getting a few dependency errors after running npm install, as long as i work them out everything should be fine right?

Comment: or do i do npm cache clean and then `platform add`?

Comment: i tried it how i said in the first comment and it didnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697733/livereload-causes-app-to-stall-on-splash-screen-continuous-loading-wheel-ion

Comment: great thanks for your update ill give it a shot i do `ionic cordova run ios -lc (also sometimes with `--device` flag even though its not neccessary

Comment: the `content` config xml line still had just `index.html` no localhost ip.

Comment: i tried the allow-navigation solution and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your iPhone did not yet prepare the debugger for iOS11. It does so when running your app the first time on an new iOS version. You have to open and run your project once using XCode then you should be fine. Please also make sure you have the most recent version of cordova-ios which is `4.5.1` (check the `<engine name=ios">` tag in your `config.xml`).

Comment: thanks - i don't have an `engine` tag in my config.xml - should i just add it? something like `<engine
 name="ios"
 spec="~4.4.0"/>`

Comment: It should be added automatically when you add the ios platform. `cordova platform add ios@4.5.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have the following tag in your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Also can you check whether this is observed only in iOS or also in Android.

Comment: yah, i've checked for this, i do. it only happens in ios....i dont have an android device to test currently but it works in the android simulator

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this with Ionic 4.  After adding iOS platform, running the following worked:

```
 ionic cordova prepare ios
```