# livereload causes app to stall on splash screen (continuous loading wheel) - Ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, deployment, build

**UPDATE**

It stopped working without `livereload` too - so now it wasn't being cause by `livereload` - but I still need help with this problem

---

After the `iOS 11` update (I think that is the cause of this because things were fine before), I am not able to use `livereload`. If I try to use livereload, it hangs on the splash screen - with the loading wheel spinning. Here is some info about my ionic environment:

```
Eamons-MBP:myapp eamonwhite$ ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
    Node       : v7.7.3
    npm        : 4.1.2 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235 

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

When I run it with `xcode`, it says this in the `xcode` console:

```
2017-10-10 15:49:17.417901-0400 myApp[8476:3520766] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-10-10 15:49:38.433127-0400 myApp[8476:3520766] Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.
```

In the ionic console, it stops before the `deviceready` event:

```
------ Debug phase ------
Starting debug of 2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356 (N51AP, iPhone 5s (GSM), iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'Eamon White’s iPhone' connected through USB...
[  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[ 90%] Mounting developer disk image
[ 95%] Developer disk image already mounted
[100%] Connecting to remote debug server
-------------------------
(lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/2F06F4BB-A7E5-4B97-87EC-A01CBEE5661A/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356'
Executing commands in '/tmp/2F06F4BB-A7E5-4B97-87EC-A01CBEE5661A/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356'.
(lldb)     platform select remote-ios --sysroot '/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols'
  Platform: remote-ios
 Connected: no
  SDK Path: "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols"
(lldb)     target create "/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device/myApp.app"
Current executable set to '/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device/myApp.app' (arm64).
(lldb)     script fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EBCC0EF-FDB9-4DE7-A961-D91B6139AEA0/myApp.app"
(lldb)     script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:50188"
(lldb)     target modules search-paths add /usr "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols/usr" /System "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols/System" "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EBCC0EF-FDB9-4DE7-A961-D91B6139AEA0" "/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device" "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EBCC0EF-FDB9-4DE7-A961-D91B6139AEA0" "/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myapp/platforms/ios/build/device" /Developer "/Users/eamonwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/10.3.3 (14G60)/Symbols/Developer"
(lldb)     command script import "/tmp/2F06F4BB-A7E5-4B97-87EC-A01CBEE5661A/fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.py"
(lldb)     command script add -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.connect_command connect
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.run_command run
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.autoexit_command autoexit
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.safequit_command safequit
(lldb)     connect
(lldb)     run
success
(lldb)     safequit
Process 7681 detached
```

Also, I updated my `ios-deploy` from `1.9.1` to `1.9.2` before this started happening.

Why can't I use `livereload`? Again, I think this might have something to do with the `iOS 11` update. Does anybody know a workaround...I have read something about `npm run watch` but couldn't get it running.

I have created a blank app to see if that would run with `livereload` and it doesn't.

Comment: this is wat i'm stressing out in your previous question i.e. `plugin are not ready` while you are using the livereload and this causes you inconsistency in your plugins and also your logs says the same . this line in your log `Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-10-10 15:49:38.433127-0400 myApp[8476:3520766] Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.`

Comment: im not sure if i follow completely, do you have any suggestions? i tried deleting `node_modules` and doing `npm install`  and `npm cache clean` if u are saying its a problem with plugins.

Comment: also just so u know...i built a blank app and ran it...and the same thing happens...how can i fix the "inconsistencies"?

Comment: Did you check if there are any logs in safari dev tools?

Comment: i havent looked at safari dev tools, ill do that - also...the problem started happening without livereload too...i ran it and it went to a whitescreen and then after that its just been hanging on splashscreen so something else is causing this

Comment: when i use dev tools...it says 'myApp' grayed out when i go to select it under `<my iphone name>`. myApp is the name of my app. but i think there is supposed to be an index.html file available there...it must not be getting to that point

Comment: @webruster , request timeout occurs mainly in two scenarios when your app try to get the required data using plugin and failed to fetch it another case would be inconsistency in your plugins , in other words improper installation of plugins

Answer (score 3):

The `wifi` on my phone was off so it wasn't connecting to `ionic`.